# "Run and forget" a link from javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a site that will keep a track of when user enters a page and how long he's there (or to be more specific, when he leaves)

I have set up a node server and I would like to run the action there, but the question is irrelevant to node itself, it's a javascript related question.

My goal is to have javascript call a certain method with specific parameters and then forget about that. However, I would like to avoid ajax if possible, I know I could do it with ajax, but I think that's an overkill and I'm not sure even if ajax would work on a node server.

What I'm looking at is something like

*User opens web page
*Javascript runs the script, let's say.
Run("http://server.com/User/EnteredPage/IDOFUSER");

and when the user closes the page
Run("http://server.com/User/LeftPage/IDOFUSER");

Point is.. I don't need anything from that call, I just want the javascript to run it, to save the data I need and that's it.

Comment: "I think that's an overkill" — More like underkill.

Comment: Many tracking services use dynamically created image elements that pass data to the server via GET …

Comment: "I'm not sure even if ajax would work on a node server" — Ajax just means "Make an HTTP request from JavaScript without leaving the page". The server doesn't need to support anything other than basic HTTP.

Comment: I know quentin, but I haven't handled node too much, and I'm a bit afraid of introducing jquery in that environment now

Comment: What does jQuery have to do with anything? Nobody has said anything about jQuery. Even if you chose to use it, Node doesn't care. As far as the server is concerned, jQuery is just a static file … or is nothing at all because it is a static file hosted on a third party CDN.

Answer (score 1):

HTTP is stateless. The browser asks for a resource. The server gives the browser the resource. The end.

The request is done and dealt with. There is no further communication about that request so the server doesn't know when the visitor has left the page that it served up. If you want to know that, then you need *another* request to tell the server about it.

The problem with that approach is that the visitor might leave the page by:

- Quitting their browser entirely
- Running out of battery
- Getting disconnected from the network

… so you can't reliably send a new request when the user leaves the page.

So the best you can do is to have the browser tell the server that the user hasn't left yet (you could do this with [Ajax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest) or (potentially more efficiently) [WebSockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API)).

Combine this with a timer based action on the server that tests how long it has been since the visitor's browser last sent an *I'm still here* message and use **that** to call your *visitor has left* function.

Comment: Hmm, that's actually a good plan.. I could make a loop that will contact node every x seconds and if the call stops, it means the user disconnected, nice!